# Caling AJAX Method for multiple hidden ids aspx

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net

I am calling a ajax method for a number of hidden client ids on an aspx page.  The ajax method returns some html to a div provided.

So the code looks like below:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnSomeProperty" Value="False"/> 
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfMyIndex" Value="0" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfCustId" /> 
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfCarId" /> 
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfVanId" /> 
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfTruckId" /> 
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfMotorCycleId" /> 


var carNode = "<%=VechileNodeTypeEnum.Car.ToString() %>"; 
var selectedCarIds = $('#<%=hfCarId.ClientID %>').val();          
ajaxMethod('/MyPage/MyMethod', { custId: custId, vechileNodeType: carNode, selectedIds: selectedCarIds }, '#carDiv'); 

var vanNode = "<%=VechileNodeTypeEnum.Van.ToString() %>"; 
var selectedVanIds = $('#<%=hfVanId.ClientID %>').val();          
ajaxMethod('/MyPage/MyMethod', { custId: custId, vechileNodeType: vanNode, selectedIds: selectedVanIds }, '#vanDiv'); 

var truckNode = "<%=VechileNodeTypeEnum.Truck.ToString() %>"; 
var selectedTruckIds = $('#<%=hfTruckId.ClientID %>').val();          
ajaxMethod('/MyPage/MyMethod', { custId: custId, vechileNodeType: truckNode, selectedIds: selectedTruckIds }, '#truckDiv'); 

var motorcycleNode = "<%=VechileNodeTypeEnum.MotorCycle.ToString() %>"; 
var selectedMotorcycleIds = $('#<%=hfMotorCycleId.ClientID %>').val();          
ajaxMethod('/MyPage/MyMethod', { custId: custId, vechileNodeType: motorcycleNode, selectedIds: selectedMotorcycleIds }, '#motorcycleDiv');
```

Everything works as expected however I dont like the pattern of repeating the code 4 times with just a few of the proerties changed - I was think I could perhaps use a for loop and loop round 4 times - not sure how I would pass the changed properties dynamically though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a function that would wrap the ajax call and use it as many times as you wish.

```
var callMyMethod = function(nodeType, clientId, target) {
  var ids = $('#' + clientId).val();
  ajaxMethod('/MyPage/MyMethod', {
    custId: custId, // is it a global variable?
    vehicleNodeType: nodeType,
    selectedIds: ids 
  }, target);
};

callMyMethod('<%=VechileNodeTypeEnum.Car.ToString()%>', '<%=hfCarId.ClientID%>', '#carDiv');
callMyMethod('<%=VechileNodeTypeEnum.Van.ToString()%>', '<%=hfVanId.ClientID%>', '#vanDiv');
callMyMethod('<%=VechileNodeTypeEnum.Truck.ToString()%>', '<%=hfTruckId.ClientID%>', '#truckDiv');
callMyMethod('<%=VechileNodeTypeEnum.MotorCycle.ToString()%>', '<%=hfMotorCycleId.ClientID%>', '#motorCycleDiv');
```

If there is some correlation between for example `hfCarId.ClientID` and `#carId`, you can remove the `target` argument from the function.

It should be also possible to generate these calls by iterating over `Car`, `Van`, `Truck` and `MotorCycle` but I'm not that familiar with .net to suggest it to you.